# Unity ads banner open callback

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityads

Is there any way to get a callback when unity ads banner that has been pressed?
I've tried to use rewarded video callbacks but nothing worked.

Answer (score -1):

Refer to the [official documentation](https://unityads.unity3d.com/help/unity/integration-guide-unity#banner-ads) under the *Implementing rewarded ads* section.

You can see that there is a function `AdFinished` that looks like this:

```
void AdFinished (ShowResult result) {
        if (result == ShowResult.Finished) {
            // Reward the player
        }
    }
```

and that that is added as a callback in the following way:

```
ad.Show (AdFinished);
```

Comment: I've checked, there's no callback with opened banner.

Comment: Please refer to the "Adding a callback method to your script" section on that page. It show how to create a function with void return that accepts only a single `ShowResult` argument.

Comment: So, you're saying that one of the following: ShowResult.Failed/Finished/Skipped is the same as OpenedBanner?

Comment: I have updated my answer to clarify. If you'd like, feel free to start a chat with me: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/11869748/

Comment: This is for interstitial and rewarded ad, not for the banner ad.